# Do any harvestable natural walls spawned at world gen count for stopping monster generation?

Tags: terraria

Do any harvestable natural walls spawned at world gen count for stopping monster generation?

I know [that player-made walls](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/NPC_spawning#Spawning_Basics) count, but the only natural walls with a clear player version, is [Dirt Walls](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dirt_Wall).

If I broke off a Cloud Wall, for instance, then placed it back on, would the replace wall count as player-made, and block monsters?

It seems like the more constructed walls. like Marble and Disk, block monsters, given how they're in houses made by world gen?

Comment: Most naturally occurring wall blocks have player versions, in fact many can be crafted

Answer (score 2):

From the [wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Background_Walls):

> Natural walls will not stop enemies from spawning, and cannot be utilised for Houses.

Also from the wiki, on destroying and placing natural walls:

> Certain walls, [] exist in both natural and housing forms. With these walls, the player must break the natural walls and replace them in order to allow them to count as housing walls.

This means that the type of wall has no impact on monster spawning, all that matters is whether or not it has been placed by a player. As housing walls do block monsters, and natural walls do not.

Comment: So, from that page, a Cloud Wall is a Housing Wall instead of a Natural Wall, since it can be broken from the middle, IIRC? ... Is it too late to change my use of "natural" to "generated at world-gen"?

Comment: No you’ve misunderstood, all walls that are naturally found in a world have the label “natural wall” and only become “housing wall” of destroyed and placed again by a player. So your cloud wall is a natural wall, unless you collect it all and put it back down.

Comment: And yet, the house in the cloud was inhabited by an NPC after I discovered it